# Does Robot Framework support angular 4 UI automation

Tags: angular, selenium-webdriver, robotframework, ui-automation

Does Robot Framework support angular 4 UI automation? Any documentation link would be very helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes it support,

don't what you exactly ask but this links helps you

- **https://github.com/Selenium2Library/robotframework-angularjs**
- **http://www.protractortest.org/#/**

Comment: Thanks !. I have already installed robot framework. I want reference to understand how angular 4 based UI is automated using robot framework. For now , we are not using protractortest.